# Extract a rating/ class name in scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, css-selectors

I am trying to scrape a rating from a website called msci
https://www.msci.com/our-solutions/esg-investing/esg-ratings/esg-fund-ratings/funds/omr-blackrock-global-equity/72001927

and the code changes such as for an A rating it's:

```
<div class="ratingdata-fund-rating esg-fund-ratings-circle-a"></div>
```

and if B it is:

```
<div class="ratingdata-fund-rating esg-fund-ratings-circle-b"></div>
```

Is there/ how would I be able to see if a page is `esg-fund-ratings-circle-b` or `esg-fund-ratings-circle-a`
I am new to scraping and any help would be very appreciated

Comment: You'll need to use [Selectors in Scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html), although, I recommend using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) instead for HTML parsing as it's a bit more straightforward when parsing

Comment: thanks for the comment, will have a look into beautiful soup. If I was to do selectors I was trying to do `response.xpath('//*[@class="ratingdata-fund-rating esg-fund-ratings-circle-bbb"]')` but doesn't seem to work any idea?

Comment: Maybe something [like this](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#other-xpath-extensions)

```response.xpath('//*[has-class("foo", "bar-baz")]')```